# MySQL error with CAST and concatenation

Tags: mysql, sql

Consider the below code

```
UPDATE users SET class = '-' + CAST(class AS CHAR(50)) + '-' WHERE 1=1
```

The above query throws the following error:

```
#1292 - Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '-'
```

I recently updated the class column from `int(11)` to `varchar(255)` and am trying to update every row to a format of: -class- where class is the previous int value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have updated the column from int to varchar then there is no point casting it and just use CONCAT

```
UPDATE users SET class = CONCAT ('-',class,'-') WHERE 1=1
```

if class is NULL then the result will be NULL so to make sure you are only updating CLASS with values

```
UPDATE users SET class = CONCAT ('-',class,'-') WHERE class IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: You probably mean `class IS NOT NULL`.

Comment: correct.. i was looking at probably an old documentation